# Duplicator Interpreter with HOAS

Tags: haskell, ghc, dsl

In section 2.3 of [these](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/course/lecture.pdf) really cool notes on tagless final interpreters for DSLs, Oleg Kiselyov shows how to solve the problem of *parsing* a serialized DSL expression once, and *interpreting* it multiple times.

Briefly, he shows that "fake first-class polymorphism" with the types

```
newtype Wrapped = Wrapped (∀ repr. ExpSYM repr ⇒ repr)
fromTree :: String → Either ErrMsg Wrapped
```

is not satisfactory because it is not extensible: we have to have a different `Wrapper`/`fromTree` for every *set* of constraints on `repr`. Thus I'm inclined to use his solution of a *duplicator interpreter*. This question is about how to use that interpreter with HOAS.

Specifically, consider the following language for target language bindings:

```
class Lam repr where
  lam :: (repr a -> repr b) -> repr (a -> b)
  app :: repr (a -> b) -> repr a -> repr b
```

I'm having trouble giving a *sound* instance of the `Lam` class for my duplicator interpreter. Here's what I have:

```
data Dup repr1 repr2 a = Dup {unDupA :: repr1 a, unDupB :: repr2 a}

instance (Lam repr1, Lam repr2) => Lam (Dup repr1 repr2) where
  lam f = Dup (lam $ unDupA . f . flip Dup undefined) (lam $ unDupB . f . Dup undefined)
  app (Dup fa fb) (Dup a b) = Dup (app fa a) (app fb b)
```

Is there some way to give a *recursive* instance of `Lambda` for something like my `Dup` type that doesn't involve `undefined`?

I've also tried using the more powerful version of `lam` from [this paper](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/TaglessStaged/beyond.pdf), which permits *monadic* interpreters with HOAS, though I didn't see how it would help me with my instance for `Dup`. A solution using either version of `lam` with HOAS would be great!

---

<sub>*: Oleg showed how to define a sound instance using de Bruijn indices, but I'm really interested in a solution for HOAS.</sub>

```
    class Lam repr where
      lam :: repr (a,g) b -> repr g (a -> b)
      app :: repr g (a->b) -> repr g a -> repr g b

    data Dup repr1 repr2 g a = Dup{d1:: repr1 g a, d2:: repr2 g a}

    instance (Lam repr1, Lam repr2) => Lam (Dup repr1 repr2) where
      lam (Dup e1 e2) = Dup (lam e1) (lam e2)
      app (Dup f1 f2) (Dup x1 x2) = Dup (app f1 x1) (app f2 x2)
```

Comment: That seems unlikely. You can't get from `(r1, r2) -> (r1, r2)` to `(r1 -> r1, r2 -> r2)`, which would be required to implement `Lam (Dup r1 r2)` using `(Lam r1, Lam r2)`.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia I thought the same thing about going from a `(a -> m b) -> m (a -> b)` for an arbitrary `Monad m`, until I read the second linked paper. I'm holding out for another similarly amazing solution.

Comment: @crockeea is that a "trick" that can be described outside of the context of the paper, or can I jump to a certain page to get a quick sense of what how that would work?

Comment: Section 3 of "Combinators for Impure yet Hygenic Code" has a good description, particularly page 28, where they get to the point.

Comment: One solution is to switch from HOAS to PHOAS, but I don't know if that would make your life easier or harder for whatever other purposes you need this code for. But this change would fix the three points in the bounty comment. The change is pretty straightforward - change the type of `lam` to `(v a -> repr v b) -> repr v (a -> b)`; for types which do not bind a variable, `repr` becomes `repr v`; and you will need `var :: v a -> repr v a`.

Answer (score 3):

This is impossible.

To show an example, I'll first make a very simple instance of `Lam`:

```
newtype Id a = Id a

instance Lam Id where
    lam (Id f) = Id (\x -> let Id r = f x in r)
    app (Id f) (Id x) = Id (f x)
```

Now I'll make a function that operates on `Dup`s:

```
f :: Dup Id Id Int -> Dup Id Id Int
f (Dup (Id x) (Id y)) = Dup (Id x*y) (Id y)
```

I would, from a `Lam` instance, be able to do `lam f :: Dup Id Id (Int -> Int)`.
This might look like

```
Dup (Id (\x -> x*y)) (Id (\y -> y))
```

which couldn't be made, because `y` is not available from the `x`-lambda.  (Using `undefined`s replaces the `y` with `undefined` here, throwing run-time errors whenever it doesn't work nicely.)
This is not a rare occurrence: it happens any time you use one of the variables in the other's result.

I'm not sure quite what you're asking with the stronger `Monad`-generalized one, but this happens with other `Monad`s, too: for example, with `Maybe`, you couldn't turn the following into a `Maybe (Int -> Int)` because it depends on the value given:

```
f :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
f m = m >>= \x -> if x > 5 then Just x else Nothing
```

(You could use `fromJust` on it and hope no one does this, but it's the same as the `undefined` solution.)

The `undefined`s only throw an error if the function needs to look at the other variables, though.  If you're absolutely certain that it will never be run on anything like this, (e.g. you restrict unwrapping/creation to an extensively-tested hidden-away module,) then the `undefined` way would work.

Just one more recommendation for it: use a more verbose `error` message instead of `undefined`, in case something *does* go wrong.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some work with Template Haskell, I had an idea that is applicable here. Another option would be to do it the way TH does:

```
class Fail.MonadFail m => Quasi m where
    -- All the things here, like inspecting types, generating names, etc.
    ...

-- Many instances, including
instance Quasi IO where ... -- So you can debug your TH
instance TH.Quasi GHCiQ where ... -- see https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/libraries/ghci/GHCi/TH.hs#L167
instance TH.Quasi TcM where ... -- see https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/compiler/typecheck/TcSplice.hs#L835

data Q a = { unQ :: forall m. Quasi m => m a }
instance Quasi Q where ...
```

You can find the `Q` monad's definition [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.12.0.0/docs/src/Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.html#Q).

An end user works within the `Q` monad, and it can be interpreted by any internal compiler interpreter, or the `IO` monad for debugging, etc.  Any duplication is handled by the `forall`.  You could, similarly, do something like

```
data L a = { unL :: forall repr. Lam repr => repr a }
instance Lam L where ...

myEndUserThing :: L ((a -> b) -> a -> b)
myEndUserThing = lam $ \f -> lam $ \x -> app f x
```

`L a` is easily convertible to any other `repr` you want, and if you need more functionality, just add it to the `Lam` class or create a deriving class with the extra functionality.